# Sending echo to Arduino serial port on MAC(osx)

Tags: bash, shell, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to send an echo from a shell script on some event.

```sh
echo naval > /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
```

on this `/dev/cu.usbmodem1421` serial port my Blend Micro Atmega32u4 Board is listening.

But every time I send an echo it says, resource busy.

I am not sure what can be the solution?

Arduino code:

```cpp
int incomingByte = 0;    // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);    // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {
  // send data only when you receive data:
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

    // read the incoming byte:
    incomingByte = Serial.read();

    // say what you got:
    Serial.print((char)incomingByte);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried killing the process ?, it seems it is hanging waiting  a bit broad of a question but it could be caused by numerous things.